Rudin's RCA 12.10 (Lindelof's Theorem)
12.10 Lindelöf's Theorem
Suppose $\Gamma$ is a curve, with parameter interval $[0,1]$, such that $|\Gamma(t)|<1$ if $t<1$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$. If $g \in H^{\infty}$ and
$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow 1} g(\Gamma(t))=L
$$
then g has radial limit $L$ at 1 .
(It follows from Exercise 14, Chap. 14, that $g$ actually has nontangential limit $L$ at 1.)
Proof Assume $|g|<1, L=0$, without loss of generality. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. There exists $t_0<1$ so that, setting $r_0=\operatorname{Re} \Gamma\left(t_0\right)$, we have
$$
|g(\Gamma(t))|<\epsilon \quad \text { and } \quad \operatorname{Re} \Gamma(t)>r_0>\frac{1}{2}
$$
as soon as $t_0<t<1$.
Pick $r, r_0<r<1$.
Define $h$ in $\Omega=D(0 ; 1) \cap D(2 r ; 1)$ by
$$
h(z)=g(z) \overline{g(\bar{z})} g(2 r-z) \overline{g(2 r-\bar{z})}
$$
Then $h \in H(\Omega)$ and $|h|<1$. We claim that
$$
|h(r)|<\epsilon .
$$
Since $h(r)=|g(r)|^4$, the theorem follows from (4).
To prove (4), let $E_1=\Gamma\left(\left[t_1, 1\right]\right)$, where $t_1$ is the largest $t$ for which $\operatorname{Re} \Gamma(t)=r$, let $E_2$ be the reflection of $E_1$ in the real axis, and let $E$ be the union of $E_1 \cup E_2$ and its reflection in the line $x=r$. Then (2) and (3) imply that
$$
|h(z)|<\epsilon \quad \text { if } \quad z \in \Omega \cap E .
$$
Pick $c>0$, define
$$
h_c(z)=h(z)(1-z)^c(2 r-1-z)^c
$$
for $z \in \Omega$, and put $h_c(1)=h_c(2 r-1)=0$. If $K$ is the union of $E$ and the bounded components of the complement of $E$, then $K$ is compact, $h_{\mathrm{c}}$ is continuous on $K$, holomorphic in the interior of $K$, and (5) implies that $\left|h_c\right|<\epsilon$ on the boundary of $K$. Since the construction of $E$ shows that $r \in K$, the maximum modulus theorem implies that $\left|h_c(r)\right|<\epsilon$.
Letting $c \rightarrow 0$, we obtain (4).
My question:
Why do we have $r\in K$?
